# Extract specific data from a String in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am capturing some data after taking a user through a number of steps. This data is successfully being captured in the below String format. Note that due to some limitations, I don't have an option to get this data in any other format.

There are two counts that are being captured. One is a Lap and then within each lap, the number of Reps.

```
Lap 1 Rep 1, 11, Lap 1 Rep 2, 12, Lap 1 Rep 3, 15, Lap 2 Rep 1, 22, Lap 2 Rep 2, 24, Lap 2 Rep 3, 29
```

I need to get the below values from the above code in a PHP Array.

1. 11
2. 12
3. 15
4. 22
5. 24
6. 29

Please note that since the user selected the number of Laps and Reps in the process, therefore Laps and Reps can go to double-digit as well. But when I am getting the above values, I have the total count of Laps and Reps as well. Like in the above example, I also have the Laps being 2 and Reps of each Lap being 3.

Can anyone help?

Comment: tried anything?

Comment: I tried str_replace but it can only replace the values. Maybe I am not using it properly. I need a solution to get only the required data in a PHP Array.

Comment: Probably regex, with a good example being: `Lap \d Rep \d, (\d+)` (*well I wouldn't say good, but it gets the point across.*)

Comment: Can you please share the code in an answer? Would be of great help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will accomplish what you want.  I first split the string by using the explode function, then I only keep every other element by using the mod function and checking the value to see if it is 0:

```
$info = "Lap 1 Rep 1, 11, Lap 1 Rep 2, 12, Lap 1 Rep 3, 15, Lap 2 Rep 1, 22, Lap 2 Rep 2, 24, Lap 2 Rep 3, 29";

$i = 1;
$keepThese = Array();
foreach(explode(", ", $info) as $value) {
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
        array_push($keepThese, $value);
    }
}

var_dump($keepThese);
```

PSST: You forgot 15 in your example output.

Comment: Added. Let me try this and revert.

Comment: You are a Star! Thank you. I cannot accept the answer for the next three minutes so will do then.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: Didn't realize that in the previous answer, the Array positions were not in sequence as it was filtered. I prefer this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Like stated in the comments, you're best to run a regex query (using this as an example: `Lap \d Rep \d, (\d+)`):

```
preg_match_all("/Lap \d Rep \d, (\d+)/", $str, $matches);
```

Now if you look at `$matches[1]`, you'll get the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 22
    [4] => 24
    [5] => 29
)
```

<sup>*`$str` being the string you have there as an example.*</sup>